# Convert Avro to Parquet in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to convert Avro files to Parquet in NiFi. I know it's possible to convert to ORC via the **ConvertAvroToORC** processor but I didn't found a solution to convert to Parquet.

I'm converting a JSON to Avro via a **ConvertRecord** (JsonTreeReader and AvroRecordSetWriter) processor. After that I would like to convert the Avro payload to Parquet before I will put it in a S3 bucket. I don't want to store it in HDFS, therefore the **PutParquet** processor seems not to be applicable.

I would need a processor such as: **ConvertAvroToParquet**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Martin, you can use a very handy processor `ConvertAvroToParquet` which I recently contributed in `Nifi`. It should be available in latest version.

The purpose of this processor is exactly similar to what you are looking for. For more details on this processor & why it was created : [Nifi-5706](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5706)

Code [Link](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-parquet-bundle/nifi-parquet-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/parquet/TestConvertAvroToParquet.java).

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is possible to use the PutParquet processor.

Following description is from a working flow in nifi-1.8.

Place the following libs into a folder e.g. `home/nifi/s3libs/`:

- aws-java-sdk-1.11.455.jar (+ Third-party libs)
- hadoop-aws-3.0.0.jar

Create a xml file e.g. `/home/nifi/s3conf/core-site.xml`. Might need some additional tweaking, use the right endpoint for your zone.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>s3a://BUCKET_NAME</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>ACCESS-KEY</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>SECRET-KEY</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.imp</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.multipart.size</name>
        <value>104857600</value>
        <description>Parser could not handle 100M. replacing with bytes. Maybe not needed after testing</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com</value> 
        <description>Frankfurt</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.fast.upload.active.blocks</name>
        <value>4</value>
        <description>
    Maximum Number of blocks a single output stream can have
    active (uploading, or queued to the central FileSystem
    instance's pool of queued operations.

    This stops a single stream overloading the shared thread pool.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.threads.max</name>
        <value>10</value>
        <description>The total number of threads available in the filesystem for data
    uploads *or any other queued filesystem operation*.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.max.total.tasks</name>
        <value>5</value>
        <description>The number of operations which can be queued for execution</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.threads.keepalivetime</name>
        <value>60</value>
        <description>Number of seconds a thread can be idle before being terminated.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.connection.maximum</name>
        <value>15</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

### Usage

Create a `PutParquet` processor. Under *Properties* set

- Hadoop Configuration Resources: `/home/nifi/s3conf/core-site.xml`,
- Additional Classpath Reources: `/home/nifi/s3libs`,
- Directory: `s3a://BUCKET_NAME/folder/` (EL available)
- Compression Type: tested with NONE, SNAPPY
- Remove CRC: true

The flow-file must contain a `filename` attribute - No fancy chars or slashes.

Comment: This is captured under Nifi-5706